# Where did Network Manager xfce plugin go?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, network-manager, xfce, xfce-panel

After doing `apt update` and `apt dist-upgrade` of Xubuntu 16.04, the nm panel plugin seems to have disappeared, both from my panel and the list of plugins.

Note the lack of Network Manager.

(Networking still works, though.)

[image: Note the lack of Network Manager.]

Contents of ~/.xsession-errors:

```
ron@haggis:~$ dir .xsession-errors
-rw------- 1 ron ron 153 2018-02-03 13:38:20 .xsession-errors
ron@haggis:~$ cat .xsession-errors
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: im-config pre-start process (2085) terminated with status 127
```

The timestamp is from when I last logged in.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Usually executable is named `nm-applet`.

It is installable with

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome
```

It should autostart because of `/etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop`.

Manual restart is possible with

```
killall nm-applet
nm-applet &
```

Comment: Thanks.  The package was already installed, but not running, even though /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop exists, and the relevant item is selected in `Session and Startup`.  Solution was `nm-applet &`.

Comment: Where should/can I look to see why nm-app didn't autostart?

Comment: Check `~/.xsession-errors`.

Comment: I added the details to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Network manager loads in the "Notification Area" of the panel.  If you don't have this as one of the items in a panel, you won't see it.